# Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I have been using

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&safe=active&q={0}&start={1}
```

in my application to search a term in google and return results.

Initially it is working properly.. but after sometime it is giving an error

> "Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors"

Answer (score 9):

To understand what's going on is enough to read the red message in the given URL:

http://code.google.com/apis/errors

*"Note: The Google Search and Language APIs shown to the right have been officially deprecated. They will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but **the number of requests you may make per day will be limited**. Please visit the documentation for each API for further details and alternatives."*

It says the Web Search API has been deprecated and you should look for an alternative.
I think you probably made too many requests, and they have been limited (see the bold text).

Comment: Most probably because those APIs made another step forward to deletion. Read this URL: [link](https://developers.google.com/errors/?csw=1)

Comment: Removing URLs describing errors in API results is the *last* thing you do, after you've turned the API off entirely.  This is just a sloppy error on Google's part.